# Garbage Collector Running Frequently in Tomcat Web App with No User Code Running

Tags: java, tomcat, optimization, garbage-collection

I've implemented a Web App that includes Web Services and some background processes (threads) one of which is started by the Spring TaskScheduler (started only once but run constantly.. checking for other slave processes to start to handle things principally via a DB). Functionally it all runs fine but I'm in the process of tuning things up and I'm seeing an unacceptable and cyclical CPU consumption on the associated JRE. Tomcat version 8.5.29 JVM/JRE (jdk_1.8.0_171).

Suspecting that my code was inefficient and causing the GC to run unnecessarily (or just tune the GC correctly in any case), I've implemented a suggestion from another thread (that they rather aggressively threw me out of and in bad form) for tracing GC activity and have taken a close look at the associated documentation.

Once done, I was getting many GC related messages which led me to the next step. As I was debugging the user code, I couldn't make sense of (or correlate with my User Code activity) the GC invocations which are plentiful. So, in debugging mode, I put some breakpoints in all the executing User Code effectively paralyzing ALL User Code related execution and the cyclical GC messages continue at their rhythm as when the User Code is running. The results are that (independently whether the User Code is running or not) every 10-11 seconds the GC is invoked and runs for approx. 11-12 seconds.

Keeping in mind that with the User Code TOTALLY blocked.. this is a sample output..

```
2019-10-28T13:12:07.358+0100: 6206.987: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 201649K->160689K(264704K), 0.0019574 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:17.675+0100: 6217.304: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->320K(41472K)] 201649K->160761K(264704K), 0.0019036 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:17.899+0100: 6217.527: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41280K->256K(41472K)] 201721K->160809K(264704K), 0.0019992 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:18.128+0100: 6217.756: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 201769K->160785K(264704K), 0.0022651 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:18.352+0100: 6217.981: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->288K(41472K)] 201745K->160873K(264704K), 0.0020136 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:18.575+0100: 6218.203: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41248K->256K(41472K)] 201833K->160865K(264704K), 0.0019503 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:18.793+0100: 6218.422: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 201825K->160889K(264704K), 0.0019472 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:19.012+0100: 6218.641: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 201849K->160913K(264704K), 0.0019231 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:19.241+0100: 6218.870: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 201873K->160897K(264704K), 0.0022029 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:19.459+0100: 6219.088: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->224K(41472K)] 201857K->160905K(264704K), 0.0024031 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:19.685+0100: 6219.313: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 201865K->160945K(264704K), 0.0018694 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:19.902+0100: 6219.531: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->288K(41472K)] 201905K->160985K(264704K), 0.0019840 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:20.123+0100: 6219.752: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41248K->224K(41472K)] 201945K->160929K(264704K), 0.0021776 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:20.338+0100: 6219.967: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->224K(41472K)] 201889K->160929K(264704K), 0.0018897 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:20.555+0100: 6220.183: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 201889K->160977K(264704K), 0.0019590 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:20.771+0100: 6220.399: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 201937K->160953K(264704K), 0.0022302 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:20.991+0100: 6220.619: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 201913K->161001K(264704K), 0.0020969 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:21.229+0100: 6220.858: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->288K(41472K)] 201961K->161041K(264704K), 0.0018507 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:21.445+0100: 6221.074: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41248K->224K(41472K)] 202001K->160985K(264704K), 0.0023642 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:21.659+0100: 6221.288: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 201945K->161017K(264704K), 0.0019729 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:21.875+0100: 6221.504: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 201977K->161025K(264704K), 0.0019721 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:22.109+0100: 6221.738: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 201985K->161033K(264704K), 0.0021257 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:22.338+0100: 6221.966: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 201993K->161041K(264704K), 0.0018824 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:22.565+0100: 6222.194: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 202001K->161017K(264704K), 0.0019543 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:22.785+0100: 6222.414: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 201977K->161049K(264704K), 0.0019685 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:23.002+0100: 6222.630: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202009K->161049K(264704K), 0.0018725 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:23.240+0100: 6222.869: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 202009K->161025K(264704K), 0.0021566 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:23.451+0100: 6223.080: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->224K(41472K)] 201985K->161025K(264704K), 0.0020730 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:23.682+0100: 6223.311: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 201985K->161057K(264704K), 0.0019011 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:23.933+0100: 6223.561: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 202017K->161025K(264704K), 0.0018953 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:24.185+0100: 6223.813: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 201985K->161065K(264704K), 0.0019484 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:24.419+0100: 6224.048: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->288K(41472K)] 202025K->161097K(264704K), 0.0019002 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:24.644+0100: 6224.272: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41248K->256K(41472K)] 202057K->161081K(264704K), 0.0018661 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:24.872+0100: 6224.501: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202041K->161081K(264704K), 0.0019496 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:25.092+0100: 6224.721: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 202041K->161049K(264704K), 0.0022255 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:25.319+0100: 6224.948: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 202009K->161081K(264704K), 0.0020412 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:25.537+0100: 6225.165: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202041K->161081K(264704K), 0.0019278 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:25.762+0100: 6225.391: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 202041K->161057K(264704K), 0.0020179 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:25.979+0100: 6225.608: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 202017K->161089K(264704K), 0.0018991 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:26.252+0100: 6225.880: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 202049K->161057K(264704K), 0.0018755 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:26.484+0100: 6226.112: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 202017K->161089K(264704K), 0.0019254 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:26.695+0100: 6226.324: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202049K->161089K(264704K), 0.0019129 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:26.918+0100: 6226.547: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->288K(41472K)] 202049K->161121K(264704K), 0.0018535 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:27.156+0100: 6226.785: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41248K->256K(41472K)] 202081K->161097K(264704K), 0.0019399 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:27.387+0100: 6227.016: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202057K->161097K(264704K), 0.0020594 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:27.615+0100: 6227.244: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202057K->161097K(264704K), 0.0021954 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:27.832+0100: 6227.461: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202057K->161097K(264704K), 0.0020552 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:28.047+0100: 6227.676: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->256K(41472K)] 202057K->161097K(264704K), 0.0021104 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:28.266+0100: 6227.895: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->224K(41472K)] 202057K->161073K(264704K), 0.0019352 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:28.474+0100: 6228.103: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->224K(41472K)] 202033K->161073K(264704K), 0.0020573 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:28.690+0100: 6228.319: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41184K->256K(41472K)] 202033K->161105K(264704K), 0.0023471 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-10-28T13:12:39.012+0100: 6238.641: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 41216K->288K(41472K)] 202065K->161137K(264704K), 0.0020514 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

If you look at timestamps you can infer what I mean by cyclical.. I could provide much more output but it's always the same (at least during the 1-2 hours that I was monitoring it).

So my questions are.. (1) WHAT would be causing these GC invocations, (2) WHY so many and, of course, (3) HOW this can be controlled and/or avoided.. it really takes up an annoying amount of CPU.

Comment: "*The results are that (independently whether the User Code is running or not) every 10-11 seconds the GC is invoked and runs for approx. 11-12 seconds*". That's not what the log says. According to the log, each gc takes ~2ms, but the time between the gc runs is much shorter either (except for the very first, which is truly 10s)

Comment: The first logged gc you've posted, happened at `2019-10-28T13:12:07`, the next one happend `13:12:17.675`. That's truly ten seconds later. The 3rd gc happened at `13:12:17.899`, which is less than a second after that. Then, fifty gc events follow until `13:12:39`. Fifty gc events within 22s. Which kind of math makes "every 10-11 seconds" out of that? And where do you see that the duration of the gc is "11-12 seconds"?

Comment: Let me explain what your looking at.. the first message shown is at 12:07.358 (this is from the previous cycle), the next one is at 13:12:17.675 (10-11 seconds later) and the GC pumps out messages continuously until 13:12:28.690 (11-12 seconds later) and then there is nothing until the next cycle begins at 13:12:39.012 (10-11 seconds later) . I neither know nor care if each message represents an independent GC invocation or not as the cycle is pump out X messages (each about 200 ms apart) during a total interval of 11-12 seconds.. So I hope this is now clear.. any answers to the questions?

Comment: Well, at least you've supplied an answer.. "the log don't tells".. yeah, that's the point. And no, I' don't care what the GC does internally (whatever it is, I'm sure it does it very well), I'd just like some insights to the problem and maybe useful answers to the questions and one of them was not whether the GC is working fine or not.. to repeat the principal question.. what would be causing these GC invocations?.. don't forget, user code execution is completely suspended so please don't tell me it's a coding problem.. although it's definitely in the implementation (Tomcat/Spring/JRE).

Comment: I doubt that there are well known bugs of Spring or Tomcat creating GBs of garbage for no reason. (But the question still is open, so everyone knowing them may jump in.) So you say, the threads are doing nothing, the garbage collector says, they are creating GBs of garbage. When there’s a mismatch between the garbage collection log and your statements, especially, when you keep repeating how little you care about anything, I rather trust the garbage collector.

Comment: I didn't say (nor mean to imply) that Tomcat or Spring have any bugs but it's clear that one or more objects running within the JVM is/are causing these cyclical collections.. you say "for no reason", but I'm quite sure there is a reason. There are no clients running so no requests are coming in through the Web Service and as I said, I've blocked execution using the debugger (dev env is STS 3.9.4) of the other running user code threads (2 in this case) by adding a couple of breakpoints (if they were still executing, there would be a lot of app specific messages in the output).

Comment: Ok, forget about the word “bug”, say, a reason that we can tell you without any information about your application and only knowing “Tomcat version 8.5.29 JVM/JRE (jdk_1.8.0_171)” and “Spring”. I doubt that anyone can do a remote diagnostic with only this information. Since, as said, the garbage collector is triggered by allocations, I suggest to use monitoring/profiling tools to spot the allocation sites. Knowing who is doing the allocations is the first step to find out why these allocations are made.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer to the first question. By suspending/resuming the various threads running in the environment, the culprit is the ContainerBackgroundProcessor Daemon thread. When I suspend this thread, all GC invocations cease and everything seems to run perfectly (including Web Service requests). Resume the thread, the GC starts working pretty hard again at the same cyclic frequency. Suspend it, the GC invocations stop.. etc..

I suppose the second question is irrelevant at this point.

As for the third question, an incomplete answer is just "Suspend the thread". Incomplete because although easy in a dev environment, it's obviously troublesome in production. Not to mention that (although all the functionality seemed to work fine with some limited testing) Tomcat starts up that Thread for what one would expect is a good reason and all the implications of suspending it are unknown (to me at least).

I've done some investigations on this and there is little info available and sketchy at best. The Tomcat softdocs don't really help much either simply saying "Private thread class to invoke the backgroundProcess method of this container and its children after a fixed delay."

I suspect it is started because of the thread we start via the TaskScheduler we're using. This is set for a FixedDelay of 30 seconds (which I understand is only invoked when the main loop of the thread exits.. or the Job ends so to speak) and the thread runs constantly exiting only in exceptional situations.

So, maybe someone can indicate if this maybe IS caused by a Tomcat bug (version 8.5.29) or maybe a "feature" but, in any case, how to best deal with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer - It's a feature (perhaps it could be implemented better, perhaps not).

After a thorough debugging with the Tomcat source code, I've confirmed it has to do with the Hot Reload capabilities of Tomcat. This is easily disabled by setting the Context element of the server.xml.

```
<Context ... reloadable="false">
```

Some details for those who might care..

The ContainerBackgroundProcessor invokes the StandardContext.backgroundProcess method which in turn invokes the WebappLoader.backgroundProcess method where the "reloadable" flag is checked. When true, it proceeds to check all "resources" (classes, libraries, etc..) which may have been modified after the last cached version (in my humble implementation there are a whopping 11,841 of these initially).

For each resource, it builds a new String concatenating "/WEB-INF/classes" to the resource path name.. hence 12K temporary Strings that the GC will cleanup shortly thereafter. This is cyclic by design running every X seconds (parameter backgroundProcessorDelay which by default is 10). But I believe that the CPU consumption is much more due to the processing executing here (11 nested methods need to be called for each "resource" to check if it has been modified) than the GC work although that may contribute somewhat to the load.

To me, this hot reload feature is not at all worth the overhead.. even in a development environment and its benefits are questionable from what I've seen.

My advice, turn it off.